# Py_FinalizeEx was not declared in this scope

Tags: python, c++

I am running the following code for embedding Python in C++ and am getting an error. I've taken the example code from https://docs.python.org/3/extending/embedding.html

```
#define PY_SSIZE_T_CLEAN
#include <Python.h>

int
main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    wchar_t *program = Py_DecodeLocale(argv[0], NULL);
    if (program == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Fatal error: cannot decode argv[0]\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    Py_SetProgramName(program);  /* optional but recommended */
    Py_Initialize();
    PyRun_SimpleString("from time import time,ctime\n"
                       "print('Today is', ctime(time()))\n");
    if (Py_FinalizeEx() < 0) {
        exit(120);
    }
    PyMem_RawFree(program);
    return 0;
}
```

The error is:
‘Py_FinalizeEx’ was not declared in this scope.

Comment: What version of python? Docs say new in 3.6.

Comment: I have 3.5 actually

Comment: I installed 3.7, but now when I run my code using: g++ embed.cpp -o emb -I/usr/include/python3.7m/ -lpython3.7m, I get the following error:
Python.h: No such file or directory. 
Earlier I have 5's instead of 7's in the compilation command.